# New Obect of bean for each invocation in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working in a spring boot application , where I have one controller layer , one service layer for business logic , then call goes to another service layer which interact with some external REST services.

[image: Flow Something like this]

In last layer where I am connecting with external REST services , I am using restTemplete but by getting the restTemplete object from a bean with some SSL security and authentication.

Something like this 
in Service C

```
  @Autowired
private RestTemplate gcssRestTemplate;
```

and a bean which is returning the restTemplate object

```
@Bean()
RestTemplate gcssRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder)
        throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

    return restTemplateBuilder.build());
    }
```

Now I am intending to do it in some way where every time I will get a new object of restTemplete , for each call of "C" service level method say ,  getGETResponse() , which is actually using this restTemplete to calling the external world.

I tried with bean creating by scope “prototype” but it did not work as I expect.

Can any one suggest any way out by which I can specify when ever a new call invoked in last layer of service(serve c in picture) for method "getGETResponse()", a new object of restTemplete will we wared up with that.

Comment: This is the most important sentence, "_I tried with bean creating by scope “prototype” but it did not work as I expect._" Please edit the question to explain these three items in detail: **1)** What did you try? **2)** What did you expect? **3)** What result did you actually get?

Comment: Additionally, you have not explained _why_ you want a different instance each time.  This is inefficient and not normally necessary.